# NextJs TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: javascript, error-handling, next.js, typeerror

NextJs TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split').

This error comes in yet I have not used split anywhere in my code. I understand it may be coming from installed node modules. How do I solve this error?

Comment: You can check stack trace to know what dependency throw this error and where it called from your code.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution for this. And what data fetching are you using. I have a similar error

Comment: It came from an npm module next connect. I have since stopped using that module.